# OpenSSL_encrypt returning an incorrect cyphertext?

Tags: php, openssl, aes

I am trying to use the `openssl_encrypt` function in PHP, this is my code:

```
<?php

$message = hex2bin("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff");
$key = hex2bin("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
$method = "AES-128-ECB";

$cyphertext = openssl_encrypt($message, $method, $key);
echo bin2hex(base64_decode($cyphertext)) . "\n";

?>
```

According to [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) (See page 35) and also [this online AES Calculator](http://testprotect.com/appendix/AEScalc), this should result in the following cyphertext:

```
69c4e0d86a7b0430d8cdb78070b4c55a
```

but instead my code returns this string:

```
69c4e0d86a7b0430d8cdb78070b4c55a954f64f2e4e86e9eee82d20216684899
```

What am I doing wrong? Does the openssl implementation use a different blocksize?

And yes, I do know that I'm not supposed to use ECB, but this is only for testing purposes, as soon as I have figured out why this doesn't work I'll switch to CBC.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from [the php docs' comments](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-encrypt.php#109598), emphasis by me:

> In plain english, the buffer must be padded up to blockSize. **If the
>   buffer is already a multiple of blockSize, you add an entire new
>   blockSize bytes as padding.**
>
> The value of the padding bytes MUST be the number of padding bytes as
>   a byte...
>
> So 5 bytes of padding will result in the following bytes added at the
>   end of the ciphertext: [ 0x05 ][ 0x05 ][ 0x05 ][ 0x05 ][ 0x05 ]
>
> Hope this saves someone else a few hours of their life.

Your message is one full block. Thus, the implementation of `openssl_encrypt` adds a padding block. This is why the second half of your result (which you did not expect) neatly decrypts to

```
0x10101010101010101010101010101010
```

using plain aes with that key - it is a padding added by the implementation, because plain aes is not the same as aes-cbc.